Which program started dnsmasq?
So I used dnscrypt-proxy which controlled by systemctl/systemd
but when computer boot up, i noticed that there's 2 instance of dnsmasq that occupies port 53 in different interfaces, 1 spawned by multipass, 1 without parent (parent is init)
tcp  0  0 10.61.124.1:53  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  34743/dnsmasq
tcp  0  0 127.0.2.1:53    0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  9022/dnscrypt-proxy
tcp  0  0 240.1.0.1:53    0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  9022/dnscrypt-proxy
tcp  0  0 127.0.0.53:53   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  2540/systemd-resolv
tcp  0  0 192.168.8.3:53  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  9022/dnscrypt-proxy
tcp  0  0 127.0.0.1:53    0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  9022/dnscrypt-proxy
tcp  0  0 x.y.z.a:53  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  xxx/dnsmasq
tcp  0  0 a.b.c.d:53  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  xxx/dnsmasq

i see that the configuration of dnsmasq is on:
/etc/dnsmasq.d
├── libvirt-daemon -> /etc/dnsmasq.d-available/libvirt-daemon
└── lxc -> /etc/dnsmasq.d-available/lxc
/etc/dnsmasq.d-available
├── libvirt-daemon
└── lxc
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/dnsmasq.conf --> contains xml

there's no /etc/dnsmasq.conf like normally it do in the past.
from dpkg, there's only dnsmasq-base installed.
I do killall -9 dnsmasq after booting to make multipass able to run (since it always error stuck cannot bind to some interface, it's own dnsmasq always stuck, so after kill all dnsmasq and sudo snap restart multipass.multipassd it started to work).
the question is, which program spawned/controls the other dnsmasq (that not spawned by multipass), and how to stop it or make it bind only to specific interface (or maybe make it just start dhcp port only, not dns)?

does pstree -A contain useful information on that? does systemctl status list a dnsmasq service?

yes checked both, parent of that dnsmasq is init, and systemctl | grep dnsmasq give nothing

get its PID (I don't know which one it is or why you'd obfuscate a PID value). Let's say it's 4242. And run systemctl status 4242. What's the result? Note: in your question, xxx are PIDs, just like 34743.

not obfuscating just i always kill it everytime computer started so i can run multipass, so i don't remember the number

Btw, I expect: lxc or lxc-net and libvirtd . You'd have to edit them so there's no conflict where they bind to.
